# Laravel - How do I inject automatically in Validation Rule Construct?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm not able to inject these variables through Laravel:

```
//...class AllowedUsername implements Rule...

public function __construct(Router $router, Filesystem $files, Repository $config)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->files = $files;
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

I get the error:

```
 Type error: Too few arguments to function ... 0 passed in.
```

Why is Laravel not doing it automatically?

```
$request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', new AllowedUsername],           
        ]);
```

Comment: One way around it is to get rid of injecting and use `resolve()` instead... so `$this->router = resolve(Router::class);` good luck.

Comment: It worked! @Kyslik But I'm curious why there is no "magic" injection. Would love to understand it more.

Comment: You can do it other way around; `resolve(AllowedUser::class)` and injection (old code) will work. You see injection works only if you let Laravel handle the "newing up part". see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#binding-basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to leverage Laravel's injection magic you need to use Laravel's API which essentially is:

- `resolve($class)` which is wrapper around `app($class)`
- `app($class, $params = [])` which is wrapper around:

> **Note**: I've changed `$abstract` for `$class`

```
if (is_null($class)) {
    return Container::getInstance();
}

return Container::getInstance()->make($class, $parameters);
```

---

Classes that you want to resolve out of container (as seen in your code sample):

```
public function __construct(Router $router, Filesystem $files, Repository $config)
```

can be resolved only because Laravel maintainers already defined binding for `Router::class`, `Filesystem:class` (example: [FilesystemServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/56a58e0fa3d845bb992d7c64ac9bb6d0c24b745a/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemServiceProvider.php)).

`Repository::class` seems to be *simple* class that does not require parameters (or require parameters that container already knows how to resolve) while "newing up" - thus Laravel can resolve it without problem.

> There is no need to bind classes into the container if they do not depend on any interfaces. The container does not need to be instructed on how to build these objects, since it can automatically resolve these objects using reflection.

Thats why `resolve(AllowedUser::class)` or `resolve(Router::class)`... work.

---

In order to let Laravel know what constructor's parameters should be sent during "newing up" you use bindings mentioned in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#binding).