# Cannot inject a dependency service in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Short summary: I have a model that I try to inject a service into, like this:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public $bar;

    public function __construct(BarServiceProvider $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

And a service provider for it, like this:

```
class BarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
   public function register()
   {
       $this->app->singleton(BarServiceProvider::class, function($app) {
           return new BarServiceProvider();
       });
   }

   public function test()
   {
       echo 'Hello, Laraworld!';
   }
}
```

It is registered within `bootstrap/app.php` via `$app->register(App\Providers\BarServiceProvider::class);` and the register method is definitely executed (so from my guessing, I'm doing something wrong within the `register()` body). However, when I try to instantiate `Foo` via `$foo = new Foo();`, I get a fatal error about not enough arguments being passed to the `__construct()` method, thus even unable to try `$foo->bar->test()` as naturally the code doesn't even reach that point.

What am I missing?

Addendum: Besides the solutions proposed in comments, there is one of my own that I am trying to avoid, that goes like this. Inside Foo's `__construct()`, we do something unforgivable in the lines of:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bar = new BarService();
    $this->baz = new BazService();
}
```

In its essence, it does work, but Laravel has inner magic allowing us not to use  such things.

Comment: Try using `resolve(Foo::class)` instead. I've written about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49223326/1564365 Lumen uses same service container as Laravel so it should be the same. Good luck!

Comment: you try to do `new Foo()`, Where this class has dependencies. try `new Foo(\App::make(\App\Providers\BarServiceProvider::class))`